# Uploading Multiple Files with CarrierWave in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, carrierwave, multiple-file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files using Carrierwave. I tried adding the multiple file ability, as shown in the github page for Carrierwave, but it's honestly the worst thing ever. I found a good source for being able to upload multiple files by following these steps.

1) `rails new multiple_image_upload_carrierwave`

2)

```
rails g scaffold post_attachment post_id:integer type_id:integer avatar:string

rake db:migrate
```

3) In post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :post_attachments
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_attachments
end
```

4) In post_attachments.rb

```
class PostAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
   belongs_to :post
end
```

5) In post_controller.rb

```
def show
   @post_attachments = @post.post_attachments.all
end

def new
   @post = Post.new
   @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.build
end

def create


     @post = Post.new(post_params)

       respond_to do |format|
         if @post.save
           params[:post_attachments]['avatar'].each do |a|
              @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:avatar => a, :post_id => @post.id)
           end
           format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
         else
           format.html { render action: 'new' }
         end
       end
     end

     def update
       respond_to do |format|
         if @post.update(post_params)
           params[:post_attachments]['avatar'].each do |a|
             @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:avatar => a, :post_id => @post.id)
           end
         end
      end

      def destroy
        @post.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to @post }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end


     private
       def post_params
          params.require(:post).permit(:title, post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :avatar])
       end
```

My question is, every file(.pdf) that gets mounted in the avatar field and uploaded has a unique Suffix identifier before the .pdf extenstion. For example XCF.pdf, and BJHA.pdf. I have a types table and one of the columns is called "Suffix". Before, when I only had one file upload, it would check in the create method to see if the first part of the extension of the filename (before the .pdf) existed in the types table under the suffix column and if it did, it would assign that type_id to that post file. If it didn't find a suffix, there would be a validation error. But now I have multiple file uploads and I have an extra table called post_attachments table and I am not sure where I should do this step to populated the type_id for each file being uploaded since each file has it's own type_id. Should it be done in the post_atachment_controller.rb in the create method?

I was thinking maybe in the create function after the if @post.save in post_controler.rb

```
    if @post.save
      params[:post_attachments]['avatar'].each do |a|
        @type = Type.where("sufix LIKE a.tr(.pdf,"")")
      if @type.exits?
        @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:avatar => a, :post_id => @post.id, :type_id => @type.id)
      end
```